# Ruby booleans operator double-bang double exclamation mark

Tags: ruby, boolean

I'm working on : https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-if-function/

Why would the first two work and not the third?

```
def _if(bool, ifTrue, ifFalse)
  bool ? ifTrue.call : ifFalse.call
end

def _if(bool, ifTrue, ifFalse)
  case !!bool
  when true
    ifTrue.call
  when false
    ifFalse.call
  end
end

def _if(bool, ifTrue, ifFalse)
  case bool
  when true
    ifTrue.call
  when false
    ifFalse.call
  end
end
```

Also I saw somebody say "The double negation ensures that no matter the initial value, you will always get true or false, never some mystery value."

But my question is what mystery value could there be when every object in Ruby is a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line "what mystery value could there be when every object in Ruby is a boolean?" is the source of your confusion. That's simply not true; the only booleans in Ruby are *true* and *false*.

I can't be sure, but I'm guessing that you misunderstood a statement like "everything in Ruby except *false* and *nil* are **truthy**. "Truthy" means that if you use it in an *if* statement, it will act like it's true. Even an empty string is truthy. But it isn't actually the boolean value *true* (unless you prepend !!, as you noted).

And since your case statement in example 3 is saying "when the value i pass in is the boolean value true|false...", it won't match unless you literally pass in the boolean value true or false.